# Perl Fastest way to download .gz file without getstore

Tags: perl, perl-module, lwp, lwp-useragent

I am interested in downloading a .gz file using perl and extract it in the script itself without storing to file. Getstore stores the file to disk. And is it possible to download the .gz file through proxy using perl LWP::Simple or LWP::Useragent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `getstore`, you can use `get()`, which can be stored in a scalar. The `IO::Compress::Gzip` module can accept a scalar reference for input. Here is an example:

```
use LWP::Simple;
use IO::Compress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);

my $content = get('http://someurl');
die if !defined($content);

my $uncompressed;
gunzip(\$content => \$uncompressed) or die "Failed to uncompress content: $GunzipError";
```

Comment: Probably you meant 'IO::Uncompress::Gunzip' since OP wants to unzip the file